# Which SAML version to use to interop custom STS/IdP and Azure AD for Office365 authentication?

Tags: office365, azure-active-directory, saml, saml-2.0, ws-federation

Trying to do interop our custom STS/ IdP (supports SAML2. protocol) and Azure AD for Office 365 authentication using WS-Fed UsernameToken Profile.

Referred this [link](https://blogs.office.com/2014/03/06/announcing-support-for-saml-2-0-federation-with-office-365/) where it says, *"Office 365 supports **SAML2.0** protocol"*. But from this [STS Integration Paper using WS Protocols](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi156b3z8rSAhXJslQKHfpjBAIQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D41185&usg=AFQjCNGxlqH1t53sHd3LOV8JMTLmcmFBjQ&sig2=hJQNZ) document (under section 2.2 Token Contents), it says *"The token is structured based on a **SAML 1.1** token..."* and sample response in the doc has SAML1.1 specific assertion only.

Which version of SAML protocol (1.1 or 2.0) to use, so that AAD accept and process the SAML assertion/ token sent by our custom STS/ IdP? or Is that integration doc is outdated?

Your answers help me whether I should implement SAML1.1 in our custom STS/ IdP or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ADAL (AKA Modern Auth) uses SAML2. Classic auth uses WS-Fed for passive applications (web interface) and WS-Trust for active applications (fat clients, like Word and Excel). Both WS methods wrap SAML1.1 assertions.

If you can, use ADAL. It will be much easier for you.

Comment: Thanks Andrew!
I required to interop using WS-Fed Passive Requester Profile with AAD. In that case, my STS/ IdP has to support SAML1.1 and wrap it under WS-Fed method. Am I right?